# WPF datagrid edit row not working

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to set a cell in my WPF `DataGrid` on a button click.

I fill a WPF `DataGrid` like this:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = GetMyList();
```

The `DataGrid` is set to `autoGenerateColumns`. I get my list using a mySql select.

The objects in my list implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

On my button click I do this:

```
MyObject o = (MyObject)myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
o.Checkin = DateTime.Now; //set date on button click is what i want
```

The data is set but the `DataGrid` doesn't update its view. Why?

Edited:
I implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface like this:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)   {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}

public DateTime Checkin    {
    get {return this.checkin;}       
    set  {
            this.checkin= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Checkin");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this did the trick:

```
   myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you dont use autogeneratecolumns and explicitly set the binding in your columnsdefinition to TwoWay?

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Checkin " >
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="Checkin " Mode="TwoWay">
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```